Tiling an Excel array in 2 dimensions, ideally not using VBA
I'm looking to tile an Excel array in 2 dimensions, as defined by another array, ideally not using VBA.
To explain better, what I would like is an excel formula for f(A, B)
Where A is boolean and =
[[1, 0],
 [0, 1]

Where B =
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4]

And f(A, B) tiles B according to bool values in A, in this case, f(A, B) = 
[[1, 2, 0, 0],
 [3, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 4]]

My initial thoughts were of =IF(MUNIT(2), {1, 2;3, 4}, {0, 0;0, 0}) but the output does not expand well.

This is my effort so far - hopefully it's fairly general:
=LET(A,A1:B2,B,D1:E2,DROP(REDUCE(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A)*COLUMNS(B)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)),LAMBDA(rowAcc,row,VSTACK(rowAcc,
   DROP(REDUCE(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B)),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A)),LAMBDA(colAcc,col,HSTACK(colAcc,B*INDEX(A,row,col)))),,1)))),1))



You could also use Makearray:
=LET(A,A1:B2,B,D1:E2,rA,ROWS(A),rB,ROWS(B),cA,COLUMNS(A),cB,COLUMNS(B),
MAKEARRAY(rA*rB,cA*cB,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(A,(r-1)/rB+1,(c-1)/cB+1)*INDEX(B,MOD(r-1,rB)+1,MOD(c-1,cB)+1))))

(Same logic as @Scott Craner's legacy version)

Here is some sample VBA code in case you wanted to go down that route:
Sub Kron()
    Dim AR As Range, BR As Range, OutR As Range
    
    ' A is the boolean array, B is array to be tiled.
    
    Dim A() As Variant
    Dim B() As Variant
    
    Dim aRows As Long, bRows As Long, aCols As Long, bCols As Long, outRows As Long, OutCols As Long
    
    Dim aRow As Long, aCol As Long, bRow As Long, bCol As Long, outRow As Long, outCol As Long
    
    Dim Out() As Integer
    
    Set AR = Range("A1:C2")
    Set BR = Range("D1:F3")
    Set OutR = Range("Q1")
    
    A = AR.Value
    B = BR.Value
    
    aRows = UBound(A, 1)
    aCols = UBound(A, 2)
    
    bRows = UBound(B, 1)
    bCols = UBound(B, 2)
    
    
    outRows = aRows * bRows
    OutCols = aCols * bCols
    
    ReDim Out(outRows, OutCols)
    
    ' Loop over boolean array A
    
    outRow = 1
    For aRow = 1 To aRows
        outCol = 1
        For aCol = 1 To aCols
        
            ' Only call Tile if A contains 1
            
            If A(aRow, aCol) = 1 Then Call Tile(Out, B, outRow, outCol, bRows, bCols)
            
            outCol = outCol + bCols
        Next aCol
        outRow = outRow + bRows
    Next aRow
          
    OutR.Resize(outRows, OutCols) = Out
     
End Sub

Private Sub Tile(Out, T, startRow, startCol, height, width)
    Dim tileRow As Long
    Dim tileCol As Long
    Dim outRow As Long
    Dim outCol As Long
    
    'Loop over tiling array locally called T
    
    outRow = startRow
    For tileRow = 1 To height
        outCol = startCol
        For tileCol = 1 To width
            Out(outRow, outCol) = T(tileRow, tileCol)
            outCol = outCol + 1
        Next tileCol
        outRow = outRow + 1
    Next tileRow
End Sub


This looks like It works perfectly, thanks! I guessing by the extent of that formula that you may not recommend this to be done like this, and rather with VBA if it were possible?

It would be interesting to compare the performance of this against a VBA solution - I'm guessing that VBA might be faster. Again, in VBA it would just be some nested loops and might be a bit easier to read. So in a situation where it's acceptable to use VBA, that might be the way to go, but I think either approach would be OK.

To return the Kronecker product of two arrays, try the following Python code:
a = xl("A1:B2")
b = xl("D1:E2")

np.kron(a,b)


If you've never used Python in Excel before, please see: Get started with Python in Excel
Alternative Method 1:
For improved performance on larger arrays, you could also try using bisection:
=LET(a,A1:C100,b,E1:I1000,BiROW(a,LAMBDA(r,BiCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,c*b)))))

Where BiCOL and BiROW are custom lambda functions defined in Name Manager:
BiCOL:
=LAMBDA(array,function,IF(COLUMNS(array)=1,function(array),LET(n,QUOTIENT(COLUMNS(array),2),HSTACK(BiCOL(TAKE(array,,n),function),BiCOL(DROP(array,,n),function)))))

BiROW:
=LAMBDA(array,function,IF(ROWS(array)=1,function(array),LET(n,QUOTIENT(ROWS(array),2),VSTACK(BiROW(TAKE(array,n),function),BiROW(DROP(array,n),function)))))

Alternative Method 2:
If you would prefer to use a REDUCE-VSTACK/HSTACK approach, performance can also be improved by stacking the results in pairs, as opposed to linear stacking:
=LET(
    a, A1:C100, b, E1:I1000,
    kpλ, MAP(a,LAMBDA(n,LET(m,n*b,LAMBDA(m)))),
    i, SEQUENCE(CEILING.MATH(LOG(ROWS(kpλ),2),1)),
    j, SEQUENCE(CEILING.MATH(LOG(COLUMNS(kpλ),2),1)),
    λ, LAMBDA(fx,LAMBDA(l,k,LET(w,WRAPROWS(l,2),MAP(TAKE(w,,1),DROP(w,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,IF(TYPE(y)=16,x(),fx(x(),y())),LAMBDA(z))))))),
    join_x, BYROW(kpλ,LAMBDA(r,REDUCE(r,j,λ(HSTACK)))),
    join_y, INDEX(REDUCE(join_x,i,λ(VSTACK)),1),
    join_y()
)

For a generalized version of this method, please see Peter Bartholomew's MAPλ function: https://gist.github.com/pbartxl
Alternative Method 3:
Another relatively efficient option is to use TOCOL with SORTBY and WRAPROWS; however, this method can only output a maximum of 1,048,576 total elements, due to the limitations of TOCOL:
=LET(
    a, A1:D128, b, F1:M256,
    v, TOCOL(a)*TOROW(b),
    λ, LAMBDA(x,fx,TOCOL(IF({1},fx(IF({1},SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),x)),v))),
    WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(v),λ(a,TOCOL),1,λ(b,TOROW),1),COLUMNS(a)*COLUMNS(b))
)


Oh my god, that PY() solution makes it real short.

@P.b The Python code is short, yes, but not incredibly fast. The alternative methods are more complex, but they are also more efficient. I just added another option that is both short and efficient but limited in its total output by TOCOL.

To give credit where credit is due: the Python code shared by Patrick Hogan was taken directly from w3resource.com; BiCOL and BiROW were adapted from Lori Miller's BYROW2 function, which in turn was adapted from Peter Bartholomew's original BMAPλ function; the REDUCE method with pairwise stacking was adapted from Peter Bartholomew's MAPλ function, more specifically his EVALTHUNKARRλ and JOINPAIRSλ sub-functions.

Similar approach to Tom, but a little shorter:
=LET(
    _t,A1:B2,
    _a,D1:E2,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(_t)),LAMBDA(_y,_z,VSTACK(_y,
        DROP(REDUCE("",CHOOSEROWS(_t,_z),LAMBDA(_x,_w,HSTACK(_x,
            IF(_w=1,_a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_a),COLUMNS(_a),0,0))))),,1)))),1))



And just for fun, this will work in older versions:
=IFERROR(
    IF(INDEX($A$1:$B$2,INT((ROW($A1)-1)/ROWS($D$1:$E$2))+1,INT((COLUMN(A$1)-1)/COLUMNS($D$1:$E$2))+1)=0,
        0,
        INDEX($D$1:$E$2,MOD((ROW($A1)-1),ROWS($D$1:$E$2))+1,MOD((COLUMN(A$1)-1),COLUMNS($D$1:$E$2))+1))
    ,"")

Drag it over and down sufficient for the array size.


This would be my approach in Office 365:
=LET(f,LAMBDA(a,b,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)),LAMBDA(c,d,HSTACK(c,REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(e,f,VSTACK(e,b*INDEX(a,f,d))))))),1,1)),f(B1:D3,F1#))
Edit:
Looking at Tom Sharpe's answer mine is kinda similar. I used the DROP on the whole, instead of the individual REDUCE functions and wrapped it in LAMBDA to call f as in the opening post. But other than that not much different, so if you vote, at least also vote Tom's


No new logic, reducing without DROP and using INDEX, hoping for better performance:
=LAMBDA(a, b,
    LET(
        cols_a, SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(a) - 1, 2),
        h_stack, LAMBDA(row,
            REDUCE(
                INDEX(a, row, 1) * b,
                INDEX(a, row, cols_a),
                LAMBDA(acc, a, HSTACK(acc, a * b))
            )
        ),
        REDUCE(
            h_stack(1),
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(a) - 1, , 2),
            LAMBDA(acc, row, VSTACK(acc, h_stack(row)))
        )
    )
)(Sheet2!A1:D128, Sheet2!F1:M256)

It took about 6 seconds with these ranges on my Mac.

Without using any LAMBDA() helper functions:


• Formula used in cell A7
=LET(
     a, A1#,
     b, D1#,
     c, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)*ROWS(b),,0),
     d, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(a)*COLUMNS(b), 0),
     e, IF(INDEX(a,1+QUOTIENT(c, ROWS(b)),1+QUOTIENT(d, COLUMNS(b))),
           INDEX(b,1+MOD(c, ROWS(b)),1+MOD(d, COLUMNS(b))),0),
     e)


Change the last variable to other variables to see what it evaluates to.

